# Why is PHP max_input_vars setting needed?

Tags: php.ini

I have a bit weird question. Why is PHP setting `max_input_vars` needed?

PHP has a memory limit. So even if somebody sends 10M variables, the request will be terminated because of memory shortage.

What are the risks of setting `max_input_vars` to 1,000,000?

Thanks

Comment: http://lukasmartinelli.ch/web/2014/11/17/php-dos-attack-revisited.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP introduced `max_input_vars` to address a DOS attack by using hash collisions from GET or POST requests.

http://lukasmartinelli.ch/web/2014/11/17/php-dos-attack-revisited.html

A good explanation can be found here: https://events.ccc.de/congress/2011/Fahrplan/attachments/2007_28C3_Effective_DoS_on_web_application_platforms.pdf
This PDF is also linked in the article above.